# Setting the exact duration for incrementing to another number

Tags: javascript

I've made a function that increments one number to another. This works however my duration logic doesn't.

The third parameter in `.animateNumber()` is duration, and I want this to be the time spent incrementing to the new number.

So if the duration is set at 500, then it'll take 500 milliseconds incrementing from 10 (start) - 500 (end), and this would be the same for any starting and ending values.

http://jsbin.com/kepibetuxu/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.animateNumber = function(start, end, duration) {

this.style.opacity = 0.5;

var self = this,
    range = end - start,
    current = start,
    increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
    stepTime = duration / range,
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      current += increment;
      self.innerHTML = current;
      if (current == end) {
        self.style.opacity = 1;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, stepTime);
  
  
  console.log(range);
  console.log(stepTime);
  

};

document.querySelector('.value').animateNumber(400, 500, 20);
document.querySelector('.value1').animateNumber(0, 500, 20);
```

```html
<div class="value">0</div>
<div class="value1">0</div>
```

How may I fix my stepTime logic to do this?

Comment: This is not how setTimeout works. It will register events at specific tick. You should look into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just request new frames, and update the number to the approapriate fraction at that time:

```js
function animateNumber(el, start, end, duration) {
  var startTime = performance.now();
  (function func() {
    var factor = Math.min(1, (performance.now() - startTime) / duration);
    el.textContent = (start + (end-start) * factor).toFixed(0);
    el.style.opacity = factor;
    if(factor < 1) requestAnimationFrame(func);
  })();
}
animateNumber(document.querySelector('.value1'), 400, 500, 2000);
animateNumber(document.querySelector('.value2'),   0, 500, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="value1">0</div>
<div class="value2">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it adding a refresh rate to your function:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.animateNumber = function(start, end, duration, refresh) {

this.style.opacity = 0.5;

var self = this,
    refresh = refresh || 10,
    range = end - start,
    stepQt = duration/refresh | 0,
    increment = end > start? range/stepQt : -range/stepQt ,
    current = start;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
      current += increment ;
    if (current >= end) {
        current = end;
        self.style.opacity = 1;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      self.innerHTML = current | 0;
      
    }, refresh);
  

};

document.querySelector('.value').animateNumber(400, 500, 2000);
document.querySelector('.value1').animateNumber(0, 500, 2000, 10);
```

```html
<div class="value">0</div>
<div class="value1">0</div>
```

the refresh rate is there to help you understand that the increment should be based on the quantity of steps in the animation instead of adjusting the refresh rate based on one by one increments;

you can also not add a refresh rate as I've added a default value;